# Can I manually remove all Magento_%SampleData extensions from M2.1.3+ install?

Tags: magento-2.1, sample-data

So I'm looking at my production environment, and I notice a whole bunch of Magento_%SampleData folders. If I try and run the magento sampledata:remove command, I get the error:

```
[Exception]
  Warning: file_get_contents(/home/public_html/app/code/Theme/Blog/c
  omposer.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sample-data/Model/Dependency.php
   on line 109
```

However because, its a production environment, I cannot remove/change this extension for now But I was wondering if I manually disable and then remove the SampleData components, will this cause any problems?

If I go this route, how do I prevent composer from re-installing them in future upgrades?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turns out all I needed to do was create a `composer.json` file for the offending module `Theme/Blog/composer.json`, and I was then able to run the sampledata:remove command.  Which also updates the composer library and removes them from future downloads.

if you get an error when trying to run the command referencing invalid credentials, simply run:

`ln -s ~/.composer/auth.json var/composer_home/

[Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2523)

Answer (score 0):

Read the notice in the Dev Docs

[uninstall sample data](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html)

You can disable those modules but an Uninstall is not possible. the DB will still contain references to them.